# Getting pending transactions even with nonce in sequence

Tags: go-ethereum, pending-transactions, nonce

I am running a private network with 5-9 seconds block time and no diff bomb.

I am submitting thousands of transactions using a single node. The submission is managed by a job queue, and it happens at 1 transaction at a time, more or less 2 per second.

Transactions are actually contract method calls. They all have the same `from` and `to` fields, whereas `gas` and `gasPrice` start from `4000000` and `20 Wei` respectively and get incremented by 1 at each transaction (and then reset back to their default "once a while").

The problem is that after 10-15 successful transactions, the node stop sending them, even though the nonce(s) are perfectly in sequence. For example, this is my current situation:

```
> eth.getTransactionCount("<MY ADDRESS>")
87

> txpool.inspect.pending["<MY ADDRESS>"]
{
      87: "0x08f8f7ab6fe2684df11077e4dce55479e0e05033: 0 wei + 3000050 × 50000000050 gas",
      88: "0x08f8f7ab6fe2684df11077e4dce55479e0e05033: 0 wei + 3000051 × 50000000051 gas",
      89: "0x08f8f7ab6fe2684df11077e4dce55479e0e05033: 0 wei + 3000052 × 50000000052 gas",
      90: "0x08f8f7ab6fe2684df11077e4dce55479e0e05033: 0 wei + 3000053 × 50000000053 gas",
      91: "0x08f8f7ab6fe2684df11077e4dce55479e0e05033: 0 wei + 3000054 × 50000000054 gas",
      92: "0x08f8f7ab6fe2684df11077e4dce55479e0e05033: 0 wei + 3000055 × 50000000055 gas",
      93: "0x08f8f7ab6fe2684df11077e4dce55479e0e05033: 0 wei + 3000056 × 50000000056 gas",
      94: "0x08f8f7ab6fe2684df11077e4dce55479e0e05033: 0 wei + 3000057 × 50000000057 gas",
      95: "0x08f8f7ab6fe2684df11077e4dce55479e0e05033: 0 wei + 3000058 × 50000000058 gas",
      96: "0x08f8f7ab6fe2684df11077e4dce55479e0e05033: 0 wei + 3000059 × 50000000059 gas",
      97: "0x08f8f7ab6fe2684df11077e4dce55479e0e05033: 0 wei + 3000060 × 50000000060 gas",
      98: "0x08f8f7ab6fe2684df11077e4dce55479e0e05033: 0 wei + 3000061 × 50000000061 gas",
      99: "0x08f8f7ab6fe2684df11077e4dce55479e0e05033: 0 wei + 3000062 × 50000000062 gas"
...
```

As you see, everything is perfectly synchronized and in sequence, but those pending transactions are there since hours.. Any idea?

go-ethereum: v1.6.7

**PS: a loop that re-send every pending tx is NOT an option**